# if anidados en php, optimizar consulta y eliminar redundancia de código

Tags: php, html, sql

Tengo un consullta que funciona bien pero quiero ver si hay una forma de optimizar el codigo y redicilo ya que que varias lines son las mismas en los if:

```
 if($tipoReporte==1){
              if($idDepartamento==0){
                  $sql=$consultaBase;
                  $stm = $this->container->get('database_connection')->prepare($sql);
                  $stm->execute();
                  $capturas = $stm->fetchAll();
                  $result['success'] = true;
                  return new Response(json_encode($capturas));

              } if($idDepartamento!=0 && $idMunicipio==''){
                  //validar que sino viene un municipio es porque quiere todo el departamento
                  $where ="and dep.id=$idDepartamento";
                  $sql=$consultaBase.$where;
                  $stm = $this->container->get('database_connection')->prepare($sql);
                  $stm->execute();
                  $capturas = $stm->fetchAll();
                  $result['success'] = true;
                  return new Response(json_encode($capturas));


             }if($idDepartamento!=0 && $idMunicipio!=''||$idCanton!=null && $idCanton==''|| $idCanton==null){
                  //si entra aqui es por que pidio la infomracion de un municipi determinado sin cantones
                  $where ="and dep.id=$idDepartamento and mun.id=$idMunicipio";
                  $sql=$consultaBase.$where;
                  $stm = $this->container->get('database_connection')->prepare($sql);
                  $stm->execute();
                  $capturas = $stm->fetchAll();
                  $result['success'] = true;
                  return new Response(json_encode($capturas));

            } if($idDepartamento!=0 && $idMunicipio!=''||$idMunicipio!=null && $idCanton!=''|| $idCanton!=null){
                 //si entra pidio reporte de cantones
                 $where ="and dep.id=$idDepartamento and mun.id=$idMunicipio and can.id=$idCanton";
                 $sql=$consultaBase.$where;
                 $stm = $this->container->get('database_connection')->prepare($sql);
                 $stm->execute();
                 $capturas = $stm->fetchAll();
                 $result['success'] = true;

                 return new Response(json_encode($capturas));
             }

          }
```

como ven lo unico que varia es el $where

Comment: Podrias hacerlo mediante una funcion

Comment: Una función que reciba como parámetro los criterios del where y "construya" la consulta.

Answer (score 2):

Esto es equivalente:

```
if($tipoReporte==1){              
              $sql=$consultaBase;
              $where = '';
              if($idDepartamento!=0){
                  if($idMunicipio==''){                  
                      $where ="and dep.id=$idDepartamento";
                  } else if(($idCanton!=null && $idCanton=='')|| $idCanton==null){                  
                      $where ="and dep.id=$idDepartamento and mun.id=$idMunicipio";
                  } else if(($idMunicipio!=null && $idCanton!='')|| $idCanton!=null){                 
                      $where ="and dep.id=$idDepartamento and mun.id=$idMunicipio and can.id=$idCanton";                 
              }
              $sql.=$where;
              $stm = $this->container->get('database_connection')->prepare($sql);
              $stm->execute();
              $capturas = $stm->fetchAll();
              $result['success'] = true;
              return new Response(json_encode($capturas));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrias hacerlo de las siguiente manera:

```
if($tipoReporte==1){
     if($idDepartamento==0){
          $sql=$consultaBase;
     } if($idDepartamento!=0 && $idMunicipio==''){
          //validar que sino viene un municipio es porque quiere todo el departamento
          $where ="and dep.id=$idDepartamento";
          $sql=$consultaBase.$where;
     }if($idDepartamento!=0 && $idMunicipio!=''||$idCanton!=null && $idCanton==''|| $idCanton==null){
          //si entra aqui es por que pidio la infomracion de un municipi determinado sin cantones
          $where ="and dep.id=$idDepartamento and mun.id=$idMunicipio";
          $sql=$consultaBase.$where;
     } if($idDepartamento!=0 && $idMunicipio!=''||$idMunicipio!=null && $idCanton!=''|| $idCanton!=null){
          //si entra pidio reporte de cantones
          $where ="and dep.id=$idDepartamento and mun.id=$idMunicipio and can.id=$idCanton";
          $sql=$consultaBase.$where;
     }

     $stm = $this->container->get('database_connection')->prepare($sql);
     $stm->execute();
     $capturas = $stm->fetchAll();
     $result['success'] = true;
     return new Response(json_encode($capturas));
}
```

Se omite el código repetido y se pone al final, ya cuando la consulta este lista dependiendo de los if.